# I2C + cron does not running in Raspberry Pi

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, raspberry-pi3

Still confusing how to make it run on crontab after reboot, I had make this with `crontab -e` (for example):

```
@reboot /usr/local/bin/node /home/pi/mcp23017.js
```

It will running well if I run on command line (after logging in), but it won't at cron (@reboot ..).

Maybe any ideas, Thanks.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Additional information: if I try to see on process list with ps aux it will be show like:

`pi         382  0.0  0.0   1888   412 ?        Ss   05:29   0:00 /bin/sh -c /usr/local/bin/node /home/pi/mcp23017.js`

So that script is running well but not affected to I2C (MCP23017)

Comment: Under what user does your cronjob run? Whats your specific error/problem? "So that script is running well but not affected to I2C" is not a clear question.

Comment: Okay, I had make it simple to connect I2C pin on Raspberry Pi to OLED 1306, when I run nodejs script from bash terminal it will show some text on the OLED display as it should.
But when i run it after booting by cronjob the OLED doesn't show anything <-- this is the problem.

Comment: And under what user run your cronjob?

Comment: O I forgot your first question, i don't know what user it applies to, but i just set it with crontab -e

Comment: I set when logging in as username "pi"

Comment: Have you viewed in the syslog?: https://askubuntu.com/a/56811/1034948 Have you propper logging in your script where you can see on what point it fails? Like insuffecient rights/hardware not present/ready, etc? Post your mcp23017.js content

Comment: Take a moment and complete the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour, read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Oh my God, my mistake I called a script containing read to a file with relative directories, the problem was solved by changing the active directory before running the script:

`@reboot cd /home/pi/nos && /usr/local/bin/node /home/pi/nos/nos.js`

Next time I should log to a file while script running to see if there any mistake/error at background running.
Thanks btw.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is finished (because of my mistake) I open file inside script that use relative directories and causing script stop at that point. I should log the output of script to a file and look into the file for any errors may occur, especially if the script is running in background mode.